# Replace a string if it is not followed by another string

Tags: json, regex, sed

I would like to replace the `fortawesome` string (if it is not followed by the `/fontawesome-common-type` string) by the `stephane` string.

```
sed -e 's,"@fortawesome(/^fontawesome-common-types+),"@stephaneeybert\1,g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 65: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

An example input:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^0.2.32"
"name": "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons",
```

And its expected output:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^0.2.32"
"name": "@stephane/pro-duotone-svg-icons",
```

UPDATE: I went with the simple alternative of using an intermediate variable:

```
EXCLUDE=fontawesome-common-types
BUFFER=EkSkLUdE
cat package/package.json \
  | sed -e "s,\"@$REPO_SOURCE/$EXCLUDE,\"@$BUFFER,g" \
  | sed -e "s,\"@$REPO_SOURCE,\"@$REPO_DEST,g" \
  | sed -e "s,\"@$BUFFER,\"@$REPO_SOURCE/$EXCLUDE,g" \ 
  > package/package.out.json;
```

Comment: can you please add sample input with expected output

Comment: Use `perl`, `perl -pe 's@fortawesome(?!/fontawesome-common-type)@stephane@g' file` ([demo](https://ideone.com/SU1Z5S))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry if my question was not clear enough, I can see in your demo that your use case is not what I'm facing, cheers anyway.

Comment: And what is your use case? You say "*replace `fortawesome` if it is not followed by the `/fontawesome-common-type` string*". This is exactly what I suggest doing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited the question to add an explicit use case. I apologize for not having done so in the first place.

Comment: I think [my solution still works](https://ideone.com/inPN5K).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Indeed it does :-) I struggled a bit with it, because I had to change the separator for a comma since I'm using the @ in the pattern, and had to escape it. There it is: `EXCLUDE=fontawesome-common-types
cat package/package.json \
  | perl -pe "s,\@$REPO_SOURCE(?!/$EXCLUDE),\@$REPO_DEST,g" \
  > package/package.out.json;` My hat to you.

Comment: Yes, `@` needs escaping inside double-quoted string literals.

Comment: Since this is JSON, you should post enough of the document to show the document's structure. It would then be trivial to modify it using a proper JSON parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use temporary values:

```sh
exclude='fortawesome/fontawesome-common-type';
match='fortawesome';
repl='stephane';
tmpvar='EkSkLUdE';
sed "s@$exclude@$tmpvar@g;s@$match@$repl@g;s@$tmpvar@$exclude@g" file > newfile
```

All cases of `exclude` are replaced with `tmpvars`, then real expected `match`es are replaced with `repl`s, and then `tmpvar`s are changed back to `exclude`s.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` doesn't support negative lookahead functionality. Other than the obvious `perl` fallback that supports lookaheads, uou may use this `awk` as a *work-around*:

```sh
awk -F 'fortawesome' -v OFS='stephane' 'NF > 1 {
   s = ""
   for (i=1; i<NF; ++i)
      s = s $i ($(i+1) ~ /^\/fontawesome-common-type/ ? FS : OFS)
   $0 = s $i
} 1' file
```

- This awk uses `fortawesome` as input field separator and `stephane` as `OFS`
- `NF > 1` will be true when we have `fortawesome` in a line
- we loop through fields split by `fortawesome` and keep track of next field
- if next field starts with `/fontawesome-common-type` then we keep same `FS` otherwise use `OFS`